# Load an image with a data URI with PixiLoader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, pixi.js

I need to load some marker images in Pixi.js, using PIXILoader. Those images are encoded svg images, so in this form: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,XYZ`.

I observer various behaviour depending on the browser:

- Chrome/Chromium will trigger an HTTP query, for noting, but at least it works
- Firefox won't do anything. The loading starts (`PIXILoader.onStart` is fired), but no other error or completion callback is ever called, as if it was silently failing or just doing nothing.

Pseudo-code:

```js
PIXILoader.add(
  `marker_xyz`,
  marker.customIcon // a data URI
);
PIXILoader.load((loader, resources) => {
  debugPixi(
    `Done loading ${Object.keys(resources).length} markers textures`
  );
});
```

Expected behaviour would be to load the resource instantaneously (or even better, synchronously) without any HTTP request.

What could be the solution? Writing a custom strategy, or maybe loading the resource "manually" by mutating some attribute of the loader by hand?

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/englercj/resource-loader/issues/152

Answer (score 1):

After a long day of work, found the answer to my own question: you just load them as usual, and it's normal to see them appear in the Network tab because PIXI is relying on XHR under the hood to get the metadata. So they are treated the same as distant images.

My issue was actually a bug that was hidding another bug: you cannot have size in percents for an SVG marker in Firefox.

Related:

- the swallowed error issue: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/7473
- more explanation about svg in canvas in Firefox: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/7473